# Ruby On Rails Scaffold without respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

ROR scaffold is useful, but I always find myself removing the respond_to part in the generated controllers.

Is it possible to tell Rails not to generate that part?

Comment: snarking comment incoming ... don't scaffold. You'll learn more by creating all the parts yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isnt a way of skipping this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/01/custom-scaffolding-for-rails/ custom scaffol generator
http://ramblingsonrails.com/how-to-update-the-rails-scaffold-generator-to-suit-your-own-applications